# File upload WebSocket alternatives?

Tags: file-upload, websocket, server-sent-events

I'm currently try to find a solution to change WebSockets to an alternative way with less overhead for file upload. As far as I know, SSE can only download from the server, not reverse. Is there a solution to upload a file to the serve that is not WebSocket?

Answer (score 0):

File upload has been part of the web since the dawn of time. (Okay, I'm exaggerating: form-based file upload was added as a supplemental to HTML 2, in November 1995: RFC 1867, if you are interested.)

The browser takes care of the encoding, and it will be as efficient as it can be.

Most server-side languages have some helper functions for dealing with the uploaded files. And there are client-side javascript libraries that will give you a more friendly UI than the basic html form. They are often using AJAX to give you an asynchronous file upload, that won't block the user interface.

If you search for "file upload using ajax" you will find plenty of tutorials and sample code.

Comment: AJAX causes too much overhead with re-authenticate or resent headers

Comment: @zsomborv Measurable, significant overhead? If so, it might be worth showing your measurements, and explaining more about your use case, as part of your question. What is the average file size being uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use FTPS (File Transfer Protocol Over SSL) or SFTP (Secure Shell File Transfer Protocol) as an alternative which has the least overhead and can handle large file transfer however it is limited in the number of sessions it can handle.